# Javascript in IE7 and IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-ui

I have two sliders on my homepage, one is using a plugin (AnythingSlider), and the other is just using jQuery UI (jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js).  After I added the AnythingSlider to the page, the hover function on the second slider stopped working in IE7 and IE8.  This is the code for the hover function:

```
        st = null;
        $('.homepage-leftscroller').hover(function() {
           slideleft();
           st = setInterval(slideleft, 200);
        }, function() {
           clearInterval(st);
        });
```

And here is the code for the slideleft function:

```
        function slideleft() {
            v = s.slider('option', 'value');
            if (v > 0)
                v -= 50;
            ui.value = v;
            s.slider('option', 'value', v);
            f = s.slider('option', 'slide');
            f(null,ui);
        }
```

I didn't create the second slider, I did add the first slider.  The page in question is here:

http://rareculture.net/index.php

I appreciate any help that can be offered with this.  Thank you.

P.S.
The code block containing the hover function begins like this:

```
    $(function() {
        slider = $('.artist-homepage-slider .artist-wrapper');
```

while the AnythingSlider code block begins like this:

```
    $(function(){
        $('#slider')
```

Could that be the issue?  Why would it only break in IE7 and IE8?

Comment: I did!  Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell if this is related to your problem, but the following statements are assigning values to *global* (or at least, from a wider scope), rather than *local*, variables.  If you add `var` in front of these they'll become declarations and they'll be declared *locally*.

```
st = null;

v = s.slider('option', 'value');

f = s.slider('option', 'slide');
```

[jslint](http://jslint.com) can detect issues like these.